# Non-pinned Windows 10 taskbar icons

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

How could I go about changing a default icon that is shown in the taskbar for a non-pinned item? I would like to change the icon shown for each profile of FireFox that I use, so I can have a visual clue to more easily switch between open instances. I can set the desktop shortcut icons easily enough, but what about the taskbar?

Specifically, I have a FF profile for research, and one for personal things like email. Each of these links to a different version of the browser. I often have the two distinct profiles open at the same time, but the icons in the taskbar look identical. No, I don't have them pinned, and even then, when I open the separate windows, the "open item" taskbar icons go to the default one for FireFox.